# MySQL-how to merge multiple rows into multiple columns and one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

If I have a MySQL table looking something like this: for example 2014000 is a product pen , there are four types abcd with different prices. and 2014001 is another prodct telephone , also there three types efg with different prices. now I want to get the one product one line with names and values.

```
id       code         name       value

1      2014000          A          10

2      2014000          B          9

3      2014000          C         11

4      2014000          D        12

5      2014001          E        100 

6      2014001          F        110

7     2014001           G        120
```

respect result：

```
         code              name1                  value1                 name2              value2               name3              value3             name4              value4  

         -----------       ---------              ---------          ---------              ---------   -----------       ---------              ---------          ---------              
         2014000          A                      10                   B                     9                C                      11                   D                 12
         2014001          E                     100                   F                     110             G                      120                  null              null
```

CREATE TABLE T (ID INT, code INT, NAME CHAR(1), VALUE VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO  T VALUES(1,2014000,'A','10'), (2,2014000,'B','9'), (3,2014000,'C','11'), (4,2014000,'D','12'), (5,2014001,'E','100'), (6,2014001,'F','110'), (7,2014001,'G','120');

-----the followed only for two rows , if there are more than four rows, how to do it?

```
SELECT    T1.code,     T2.name AS name1,     T2.value AS value1,     T3.name AS name2,     T3.value AS value2 FROM(     SELECT code,MIN(ID) AS ID1,CASE COUNT(code) WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(ID) END AS ID2 FROM T GROUP BY code ) T1 LEFT JOIN T T2 ON T1.ID1 = T2.ID LEFT JOIN T T3 ON T1.ID2 = T3.ID
```

Comment: Please only use tags related to your question and format your question properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.code
     , t1.name name1
     , t1.value value1
     , t2.name name2
     , t2.value value2
     , t3.name name3
     , t3.value value3
     , t4.name name4
     , t4.value value4
  FROM ( SELECT code
              , group_concat(ID) ids
           FROM T
           GROUP BY code
       ) t
    LEFT JOIN T t1
      ON find_in_set(t1.ID,t.ids)=1
    LEFT JOIN T t2
      ON find_in_set(t2.ID,t.ids)=2
    LEFT JOIN T t3
      ON find_in_set(t3.ID,t.ids)=3
    LEFT JOIN T t4
      ON find_in_set(t4.ID,t.ids)=4
```